# extract JavaScript value from page web by (PHP)

Tags: javascript, php

i need to extract a value (id value) from html web page . this value 
is included in JavaScript code .

```
<script type="text/JavaScript">
var geoInstance = gioFinder("geo");
geoInstance.setup({
    id: "126568949", // i need this
    geometre: "triangle",
    type: "html",
    image: 'https://example/126568949.jpg',
});
</script>
```

my code php is

```
    <?php
    $filename = "https://examlpe.com";
    $handle = fopen($filename, "r");
    if ($handle) {
        while (!feof($handle)) {
            $text. = fread($handle, 128);
        }
        fclose($handle);
    }

    // How can you do

//right answer is . 
$result = preg_match('/(?<=id: ")(.*)(?=",)/', $text, $matches);

echo $matches[0];
//end

    ?>
```

Comment: Essentially what you are asking is how to write a text parser for the specific case above. Where is your attempts at this? Not just opening a file and reading it block by block. Where is your code that does the parsing?

Comment: What exactly do you know about your “needle”? That it’s always a 9-digit number? That its always the `id` property in this `geoInstance` parameter? This question could use a bit of clarity.

Comment: Please do not use block quotes to highlight paragraphs. Look at posts from experienced users, and copy their style - people will spend more time on your question if you format it properly.

Comment: Since you've implemented the code from my answer, is it working now or are you still having issues?

Comment: no ! it working

Comment: Vote for my sweet  question  ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could read the file as a string and then use RegEx to find the specific value.

An example for your case could be the RegEx pattern `(?<=id: ")(.*)(?=",)`.

Then use [preg_match](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.preg-match.php): `preg_match('(?<=id: ")(.*)(?=",)', $html);`

Comment: Correct the answer  `$result = preg_match('/(?<=id: ")(.*)(?=",)/', $text, $matches);`